# Keep images inline as browser resizes while making sure its lined up correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with forcing images inside a div to line up properly with another div while maintaining its inline-block property.

Take a look at look at this image [image]for reference.

Basically, the two images (1 & 2) inside the first blue square, I want to keep them inline with each other no matter what the browser size is. But I also want the edge of image #2 to lineup with the right edge of image #3.

My current CSS for the first two images are as followed:

First the div they're in let's call it smallPic

```
.smallPic {
   width:100%;
}
```

Then each of the images (1 & 2) has the following:

```
.img {
  display: inline-block
  width:44%;
}
```

For the large picture (largePic)

```
.largePic {
   width:91%
}
```

The reason why the large picture is not width:100% is because when I set the small pictures to 50% they no longer become inline as they become too big for the div they're in. Keep in mind that they have spaces in between them (7 spaces) so I have to take that into account too. I also have no more room to increase the width of that div so that has to be constant. And since they're at such weird percentage they don't line up properly on the right edge.

So my question is, how do I force images #1 & #2 to fit inside their div, stay inline, and lineup with image #3.

Edit: I think it'll be easier if I just post the [link to my site](http://staging.covalentactivewear.com/index.php/womens/shorty-short.html) so you guys can see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `padding` to `0px` in the container and `margin` to `0px` in the images. Remaining are optional.

```css
.smallPic {
   width:100%;
   padding:0px;
   overflow-x:hidden;
   border:0px;
}
.img {
  display: inline-block;
  width:50%;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  border:0px;
}

.largePic {
   width:100%;
   padding:0px;
   margin:0px;
   border:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would work for you.

```css
   

.blue {
background-color: #00f;
width: 100%;
padding: 5px;
overflow: auto;
}
.one, .two {
display: inline-block;
width: 48.5%;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid;
background-color: #f00;
}
.one {
float: left;
}
.two {
float: right;
}
.three {
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid;
background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div class="blue">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="blue">
    <div class="three"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to minimize your HTML, remove any extra spaces and indentation. Those are actually displayed in the browser and will make the images take more space then they normally would.

Take a look at this demo:

```css
.blue {background-color: #00F; padding:6px; margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  line-height: 0; /* this will prevent the images from "adding" additional height*/
}

.smallPic img:first-child {
  margin-right: 3px; /*small gap between the images*/
  width: calc(50% - 3px); /*must reduce the image width by the amount of the margin*/
}
.smallPic img:last-child {
  margin-left: 3px; /*same goes here*/
  width: calc(50% - 3px);
}

.largePic img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="smallPic blue"><img src="https://unsplash.it/400/220"><img src="https://unsplash.it/400/220"></div>

<div class="largePic blue"><img src="https://unsplash.it/600/240"></div>
```

jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/3cvvms27/

Comment: The HTML is being generated by PHP so I don't think there's any extra indentation or spaces...

This is it btw:


$smallPic .= '<img src="'. $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->keepAspectRatio(true)->resize(1200,1440).'" alt="'. $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()). '" title="'. $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()). '" style="display:inline-block; width:44%;"/>';

Comment: On the `.blue` div, give it `font-size: 0` as well as `line-height: 0`.